# Codeigniter Http code Aborted after loading session library

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My codeigniter website will abort any requests to a page when I load the session library. I have no idea why this happens and it's never happened to me before when using codeigniter.

I know it's the Session library because whenever I remove that library from autoload config, the site works as normal again.

I'm not too sure what is causing this issue. My config values for sessions are the default ones:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I used Firebug to see if any error messages are outputted, but all I get is Aborted http status code and the generic message of:

```
The connection was reset
```

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's the save path, you have to set it to a folder, something like this:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'folder/cache/';
```

Make sure the folder has the proper permissions set so that php can write to it.

Also, try setting the match ip to true:

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference unfortunately. I even set the folders to 777 and it still aborts the request.

Comment: Try with match ip to true.

Comment: Still nothing. Even with codeigniter logging set to 4, nothing is written to the log file either.

Comment: Try with `$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'folder/cache/';`.